# NativeScript+Js Почему исчезает контент при наклоне телефона

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Проблема: создал страничку на NSC+JS пока только делаю внешний вид. В ней простой список покупок. При запуске (телефон вертикально) все отображается. После наклона (телефон горизонтально) все исчезает. И наоборот при запуске (телефон горизонтально) все отображается. После поворота (телефон вертикально) все исчезает.
Подскажите в чем тут магия и что нужно изменить?
 Visit https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=yag2eN&v=5

Comment: 1) Поставьте из Playmarket на телефон / планшет программу Playground. 
2) Зайдите по моей ссылке, (там есть инструкция), нажмите синхринизацию. Отсканируйте штрихкод с компа на ваше устройство. 
3) Загрузится мое приложение. Редактируйте на компьютере, а на телефоне сразу будет горячая перезагрузка экрана.

В приложении пока ничего, кроме будущей разметки.
Элементы типа ДИВ расположенные вертикальной  колонкой. 

Наклоните устройство на 90 градусов. все элементы пропадут. 
Почему и как это преодолеть?


Если ни кто не знает ответа, почему ярлык "бродяга" получаю я? Разве я виноват?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я выкрутился из сложившейся ситуации, но мне не нравится этот способ.
Пользуясь тем, что в браузере есть Local Storage я записал туда переменную содержащую название экрана, который должен быть видимым в этот раз. И при первичной прорисовке содержимого 
экрана и после этого, всегда обращаюсь с начала к этой переменной, потом прорисовываю содержимое.
Таким образом. При наклоне гаджета ему приходится стирать и отрисовывать экран заново, после чего вызывается функция "что отрисовать?".
Функция, сначала обратится в Local Storage с вопросом какой экран, потом его весь заново отрисует. Но я так понял, что тут нет спецов по Nativescript